# Do rectangle textures really require the GL_ARB_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE extension in OpenGL 4.3?

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm looking for the best (as in "most natural" or "most efficient") way to render simple images pixel-by-pixel using modern OpenGL.

Since I do not want mip-mapping, I turned to rectangle textures as the - as I presumed - natural choice for this task.

I was surprised however that `glCompileShader()` refuses to accept my call to `texture2DRect()` in the fragment shader unless I enable the extension `GL_ARB_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`.

I wasn't expecting that, as I'm using modern OpenGL (I'm specifying `#version 430`) and the OpenGL reference sheet at https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf does not mention the need for an extension.

To add to the confusion, the shader compiler accepts my uniform declaration `uniform sampler2DRect sampler;` without even a warning.

Is this a bug in my OpenGL driver? (I'm running version 340.52 of the NVidia driver on Windows 8.1, on a GeForce GTX 760).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the GLSL built in function `texelFetch` to address texture image pixels by the absolute integer coordinates.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf. Although Reto Koradi's suggestion works just as well as yours on my setup, the specification says that texture() takes a floating point texture coordinate, whereas texelFetch() is specified to work with integer coordinates. So I decided to accept your answer instead of Reto's.

Answer (score 4):

The texture sampling functions with type specific names, like `texture2DRect()` are all deprecated, and not available anymore in the core profile.

Instead, use `texture()`, which is overloaded for all supported texture types. Rectangle textures are still supported, so it will work with a sampler of type `sampler2DRect`.